# Reading an int using Buffered Reader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("please enter the size of array");
size = br.read();
sarray = new int[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sarray[i] = i;
}
System.out.println(sarray.length);
```

When I tried to print the length of the array, it is showing as "51" even though i gave the size as "3".

Comment: 51 is the ASCII code for 3 if that gives you a clue...

Comment: Another hint: `BufferedReader` doesn't have methods for reading shorts, longs, doubles etc. Why should int be special then? It isn't, the returned int has a different meaning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use readLine() method instead of read() method .

```
int size = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

read() method doesnt return the exact int value of input.

> public int read()
>            throws IOException Reads a single character. Overrides: read in class Reader Returns: The character read, as an integer in the
>   range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has
>   been reached Throws: IOException - If an I/O error occurse

Ref : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()

Answer (score 6):

[`BufferedReader.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--) reads a single character and returns it as an integer (i.e. returns the ASCII code of the character).

When you input `3` to your `BufferedReader`, `read()` will read it as a character, i.e. as `'3'`, which corresponds to the ASCII code 51.

You can verify this by executing the following code:

```
System.out.println((int) '3'); // prints 51
```